# Accelerate the SciPy Griddata Function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have 3 numpy arrays:
X and Y are longitudes and latitudes, and Z are digital elevation values. All the X, Y, and Z covers the RED polygon.

However, when I make grid of the data as follows it covers the Blue polygon.

```
x = X.ravel()
y = Y.ravel()
z = Z.ravel()

xi = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x),  5000) #As you see the size of data are so large (5000 by 5000)
yi = np.linspace(np.max(y), np.min(y), 5000)

zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi.reshape(1,-1), yi.reshape(-1,1)), method='nearest') #from 
scipy.interpolate import griddata
```

How can I make it to cover only RED polygon?

[image]

The computation is also very slow, if I make it possible to compute only for within the RED polygon it would be faster also.

Comment: Simen, you can insert the image directly in your question, have a look at the small toolbar atop the SO input window.  Ciao from

Comment: To my knowledge griddata tries to calculate a value for EACH cell in your matrix (either the nearest value or through interpolation) . Thus, your goal cannot be achieved using this function, because in the result there is no "missing data" (region between blue and red). Is this correct? Also missing values inside the red quadliteral get filled up.

Comment: @HyperCube Yes, there is no missing data between blue and red in the result-they are also interpolated.

Comment: @HyperCube It is not problematic if the missing data within RED polygon is filled up. But it is problematic that the previously blank region (between red and blue) is also filled up.

Comment: A dirty solution is to perform griddata using a linear interpolation and use the resulting nan's outside the red quadlieral as a mask on your griddata() run with the "nearest" option.

Comment: @HyperCube Could you provide the full solution, it's difficult to understand your method, I have coordinates of corner ponts for the both polygons.

Comment: Just append this to your code: zil = griddata((x, y), z, (xi.reshape(1, -1), yi.reshape(-1, 1)), method='linear'); zi[np.isnan(zil)] = np.nan; zi = np.ma.masked_invalid(zi)

Comment: @HyperCube Thanks for your code, I just tested it. It seems better than have nothing. There are still some portion of data between the red and blue polygons.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

2. Slowness, you are interpolating your data on a 5000x5000 grid. OK. on what device are you going to represent your interpolated data?  Is it wort the effort? Possibly not...

.

1. The shape... this is a shot in the dark but is it possible that somewhere in your code you forgot to project the spherical coordinates over a plane? (aka mapping) --- another possibility is that your data is specified in a generic quadrilateral, but then you plot the `z` in terms of a matrix `zi`, defined on a rectangular grid.  The two possibilities are not incompatible.

Comment: 2. I am using Windows 7 64 bit, 16GB RAM, and i7 processor. So machine is quite good, but gridding taking around 5 minutes, that is too long because I have to grid hundreds of such images.

Comment: 1. The X and Y are in geographic coordinate system, and my output is also the same.

Comment: Not the computer! The screen, or the printer, is important. Say it's a a 1600x900 screen, and you have available a part of it for your heatmap, say 1000x800 pixels.  Matplotlib has to  ***downsample*** your `zi` matrix, 5000x5000 values, to be able to represent your `zi` on your device! OTOH if you use a 300x300 `zi` matrix (the actual dimensions depend on the max spatial frequencies of features that you want to represent) matplotlib can interpolate the colors in "missing pixels".  Using 5000x5000 you do work that matplotlib will throw away, DON'T DO IT (unless you can demonstrate you need it)

Comment: when zi is computed, I have saved it into the harddisk using .tif file

Comment: DON'T DO [5000x5000 gridding] (unless you can demontrate you need it) because matplotlib will trow away all the cpu cycles you spent on it. OTOH, ***if you need it, need it as in 5000x5000, gridding is slow***. It's your choice, also because I don't know the characteristics of your data.

Comment: yes i need the whole data and i am not using matplotlib anymore

Comment: Z are digital elevation values in 16 bits